# Mounting drives - different drive is listed

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

I had to do a fresh installation (ubuntu 22.04.2 server) of an old server. I forgot to save the mount settings :(

There are 4 drives, a OS drive (sdc) and 3 data drives: sda, sdb, and sdd that were previously in some sort of raid. How I remount them?

If I just run `sudo mount /dev/sda /home/uname/d1`, `sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/uname/d2`, and `sudo mount /dev/sdd /home/uname/d3`, it shows all 3 mount points connected to /dev/sda:

```
/dev/sda /home/unamd/d1 btrfs rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/ 0 0
/dev/sda /home/uname/d2 btrfs rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/ 0 0
/dev/sda /home/uname/d3 btrfs rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/ 0 0
```

Why is that?  Does that mean that all I need to do is mount sda and the raid protection is already there?

edit

```
findmnt
TARGET                             SOURCE           FSTYPE      OPTIONS
/                                  /dev/sdc2        ext4        rw,relatime
├─/sys                             sysfs            sysfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security           securityfs       securityfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                 cgroup2          cgroup2     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot
│ ├─/sys/fs/pstore                 pstore           pstore      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/firmware/efi/efivars      efivarfs         efivarfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/bpf                    bpf              bpf         rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700
│ ├─/sys/kernel/debug              debugfs          debugfs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/tracing            tracefs          tracefs     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/fuse/connections       fusectl          fusectl     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/sys/kernel/config             configfs         configfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/proc                            proc             proc        rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc       systemd-1        autofs      rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe
│   └─/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc     binfmt_misc      binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/dev                             udev             devtmpfs    rw,nosuid,relatime,size=16308156k,nr_inodes=4077039,mode=755,inode64
│ ├─/dev/pts                       devpts           devpts      rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
│ ├─/dev/shm                       tmpfs            tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64
│ ├─/dev/hugepages                 hugetlbfs        hugetlbfs   rw,relatime,pagesize=2M
│ └─/dev/mqueue                    mqueue           mqueue      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
├─/run                             tmpfs            tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3273304k,mode=755,inode64
│ ├─/run/lock                      tmpfs            tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64
│ ├─/run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service
│ │                                none             ramfs       ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700
│ ├─/run/user/1000                 tmpfs            tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3273300k,nr_inodes=818325,mode=700,uid
│ ├─/run/snapd/ns                  tmpfs[/snapd/ns] tmpfs       rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3273304k,mode=755,inode64
│ │ └─/run/snapd/ns/lxd.mnt        nsfs[mnt:[(snip)]]
│ │                                                 nsfs        rw
│ └─/run/docker/netns/(snip)nsfs[net:[(snip)]]
│                                                   nsfs        rw
├─/snap/core20/1822                /dev/loop0       squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/core20/1891                /dev/loop1       squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/lxd/24322                  /dev/loop2       squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/snapd/18357                /dev/loop3       squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/snap/snapd/19361                /dev/loop4       squashfs    ro,nodev,relatime,errors=continue
├─/boot/efi                        /dev/sdc1        vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,s
├─/home/username/data               /dev/sda         btrfs       rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/
└─/var/lib/docker/overlay2/(snip)/merged
                                   overlay          overlay     rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/(snip)
username@fileserver:~/data/music$
```

Comment: Are you seeing the contents you expect under `/.../d1`, `d2`, etc?

Comment: I think so.  It's a large collection of music and pictures. Everything I spot-checked was there

Comment: Can you add the output of running `findmnt` ?

Comment: @ckhan added that

Comment: Are you editing the output of these commands? In the top part it's `uname` and `d1`, below it's `username` and `data`, is that actually literally correct? I'm thinking your mounts are masking each other. To be clear: 1) your understanding is that all 3 drives have distinct content? and 2) you see distinct content under the subdirs you mounted and 3) the only problem you have is that `mount` and `findmnt` don't seem to have the output you expect?

Comment: Yes, I'm editing the output. Previously, they were mounted in a raid for redundancy, so they were all mounted to data/